# Android: designing layout issues

Tags: android, layout, size

I have ready many, many tutorials, I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for the 3rd time, but I still don't know how to set layouts to be compatible for multiple screens.

On android docs I found this:

> For instance, a view with a layout_width="100dp" measures 100 pixels
>   wide on medium-density screen and the system scales it up to 150
>   pixels wide on high-density screen, so that the view occupies
>   approximately the same physical space on the screen.

Ok, let's see an example:
[image]

As you can see, the resolution is the same (480x800), however the view does not fill till end. I know I should use fill_parent, or match_parent, but this is for test purpose only.

XML Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_red" >

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_blue" >

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dp or dip (`density-independent pixels`) takes the device's density into account. The purpose of density-independent pixels is to display a view in the same **physical** dimensions on screens of any density.

How many actual pixels a dip equals depends on your device's density:

- If you have an mdpi device, one dpi equals one pixel (factor = 1)
- On a hdpi device, one dpi is two pixels, which should be
  approximately as big in physical size as the one pixel on mdpi. (factor = 2)

It all gets a bit clearer on an actual device:

Your 480*800 hdpi device would be smaller in physical size than the 480*800 mdpi device. Thus, when a view fills the hdpi device's screen, a view with the same physical size (dp) won't fill the screen on your mdpi device.

Comment: I know that, I have used a formula to calculate px -> dp. As you can see on the image, 480dp = 480px (mdpi), and 320dp on the hdpi. I have edited my post, I added the XML layout file. Now my question is: how many dp should I put to fit the screen normally? 480dp or 320dp ?

Comment: If you want to fill the screen, always use match_parent (fill_parent until API level 8). There is no way you could fill any device's screen using dp values.